# JS: Compare objects of arrays and delete duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays with objects:

```
var oldUsers = [{"name": "Sam", "ext": 12}, {"name": "John", "ext": 15}];
var newUsers = [{"name": "John", "ext": 15}, {"name": "Jim", "ext": 19}];
```

Now I want to remove objects from both arrays, which are in both arrays. In this example, I am trying to remove `{"name": "John", "ext": 15}` from both arrays. Both arrays are containing 200 or more objects, and in the end I need to process the objects which are not deleted, so at the end my arrays have to look like this:

```
var oldUsers = [{"name": "Sam", "ext": 12}];
var newUsers = [{"name": "Jim", "ext": 19}];
```

Does anyone of you have an idea how to solve this problem for example by looping through the arrays? I need to compare arrays with a lots of objects and then want to delete duplicate entries with `splice()` or something like that from both arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will be quite inefficient, you'll have to start by comparing every object in one array with every object in the other array. And you can't use `==` or `===` for the comparison since they will always return false when comparing different objects. So you also need a compare function to iterate over the properties of each object to see if the other has the same properties and same values. Have a go and post what you try.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a set of keys (e.g. built as `"<name>:<ext>"`, depending on what's unique) for all items found in one array and traverse the other array checking for the presence. Then run the same thing for the arrays "swapped".